# Stay on the page after minimizing the app with WebView Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

I try to keep the contents of webView after minimizing the application. how to do? here are my codes

public partial class ItemCompte : ContentPage
{
string _fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "notes.txt");

```
    public ItemCompte()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
        var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;

        if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            if (File.Exists(_fileName))
            {
                string para = File.ReadAllText(_fileName); ;
                Webview.Source = "https://www.bcongres.com/?param=" + para;

               
            }
        }
        else if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.Ethernet))
        {
            if (File.Exists(_fileName))
            {
                string para = File.ReadAllText(_fileName); ;
                Webview.Source = "https://www.bcongres.com/?param=" + para;
            }
        }
        else
        {
              DisplayAlert( "Connection Error",
                    "Venez activer vos données de l'internet, et demarrer l'application",
                    "Try again");

        }

    }
    public async  void Conn()
    {
     
    }
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await progress.ProgressTo(0.9, 100, Easing.SpringIn);
    }

    protected void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

        progress.IsVisible = true;
    }

    protected void OnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your code, you get the parameters from the `_fileName`. And webview load the uri with the parameters. What does the websites you load now when you reopen the app after minimizing the app? Could you show what it is now and what it should be?

Comment: I want to stay in the webView page, after minimizing the application.
therefore manage the cache so that the webView keeps the contents.

so in the search for the ItemCompte page I have several TabbedPages of which here is,
  tabbedPage.Children.Add (new ItemAccount ());
tabbedPage.Children.Add (new ItemBusiness ());
MainPage = new NavigationPage (new TabbedPage ());